# ASP.NET MVC Razor & C# Array - Parser Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 view where I have an embedded code block, like this:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic

@{
    PortfolioOverviewModel item = @Model.Items[0];

//Configuration
    int[] bootstrapGridValues = new int[]{12, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4};
    int deviceWidth = 800;

// More code
}
```

The problem is, the closing `}` of the array is causing IntelliSense, and the compiler to break. Instead of closing the array, it thinks that it closes the whole code block:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic

@{
    PortfolioOverviewModel item = @Model.Items[0];

//Configuration                    Closes the whole block  v
    int[] bootstrapGridValues = new int[]{12, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4};
    int deviceWidth = 800; // Not recognized as code

// More code
} // Not recognized as the closing brace
```

Why is it mixing up my braces? Is there a way I can work around this?

**Note:** This is the entire code block. I'm not snipping out code where I may have forgotten to close an earlier brace.

Comment: The problem is the `@` in `@Model.Items[0];` (remove it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke <facepalm> Thanks, that was silly of me.

Comment: Also if it would be just regular C# code `@Model` and `Model` would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

remove @ from PortfolioOverviewModel item = @Model.Items[0];

it should be like following :

```
PortfolioOverviewModel item = Model.Items[0];
```